# Not able to understand pandas join in given example

Tags: pandas, join, indexing, merge

why data from df4 is populating instead of NaN?

```
df_1 = {"col1":[1,2,3,4], "col2": [5,6,7,8]}
df1 = pd.DataFrame(df_1)
df1
 col1   col2
0   1   5
1   2   6
2   3   7
3   4   8


df_4 = {"colA":['a','b','c','d'], "col1": ['A','B','C','D']}
df4 = pd.DataFrame(df_4)
df4
  colA  col1
0   a   A
1   b   B
2   c   C
3   d   D


df1.join(df4,lsuffix='l',on='col1')

  col1l col2 colA col1
0   1    5   b    B
1   2    6   c    C
2   3    7   d    D
3   4    8   NaN  NaN
```

I can't understand after specifying join on 'col1' and how='left' as default, why data is coming from df4? NaN are expected for df4 as there is no match of data for df1 and df4. However, only one row is populated as NaN. Also, why df4[1] is moved to index 0 in result?

Answer (score 0):

From the [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.join.html): (It names *df* as the table on the left, and *other* as the table on the right)

> Another option to join using the key columns is to use the on parameter. DataFrame.join always uses *other’s* index but we can use any column in *df*. This method preserves the original DataFrame’s index in the result.

In this example, it is joining the left table's col1 as specified, to the right table's index, which is why it is also mismatched. The other option is .merge, that would give you the expected result, but it only works if the 2 tables have the same data type:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({"col1":[1,2,3,4], "col2": [5,6,7,8]})
df4 = pd.DataFrame({"col1": [10, 20, 30, 40], "colA":['a','b','c','d']})
df1.merge(df4, on='col1', how='left')
    col1   col2   colA
0     1     5     NaN
1     2     6     NaN
2     3     7     NaN
3     4     8     NaN
```

Comment: merge operation is understandable. However, 'on' in join is not clear. When tried with `df1 = pd.DataFrame({"col1":[1,2,3,4], "col2": [5,6,7,8]})
df4 = pd.DataFrame({"col1": [2,3,1,4], "colA":['a','b','c','d']})
df1.join(df4,on='col1', how='left',lsuffix='l') ` it should have consider df4[3] as not NaN and others as NaN, but it won't happen. So, basically do join means just combining two df without looking into equality of values when 'on' is specified? Am I mixing SQL joins with pandas join!

Comment: The 'on' parameter in join will match the specified column in the left table to the index of the right table. So in this example, it looks for the item in df4's index at index 1, then 2, etc. The equivalent of SQL joins in pandas would be merge, not join!

Comment: **"specified column in the left table to the index of the right table"** Thanks @lesk_s